# Is there a possibility to host multiple hidden services on one .onion address?

Tags: onion-services, address

Is there any chance to host multiple services (like a webserver, XMPP server, ssh server) behind one .onion address? Or do I have to create a single hidden service for each service/server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple services on the same .onion address. You can forward each port to a different service.
For example:

> HiddenServiceDir /path/to/hs/dir/
>   HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
>   HiddenServicePort 8000 127.0.0.1:8000
>   HiddenServicePort 81 192.168.0.102:80

This (in your `torrc`) would expose 3 services on 1 .onion address. The first 2 live on the same host as the Tor relay. The 3rd lives on another host in the local network.

See also [section three](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en#three) of the site [Configuring Hidden Services](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are there any security issues by doing this? e.g. timing or load attacks? I will try that out.

Comment: _"Are there any security issues by doing this?"_ <-- Not that I know of, or can imagine.

Comment: Well, one "issue" is that it becomes obvious for third parties that all these services are hosted on the same machine.